# Publish from an Application to a Page (to a User Wall)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication, server-side

**What I want to do:**

Publish a post on a Facebook page each time new content is added to the website, whether or not I am logged in to Facebook.

**What works now:**

Publishing a post on my own wall.

**What I have done to achieve this:**

1. I've created an App
2. I've given the app the permissions needed
   following http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=[my appId]   &next=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&req_perms=read_stream,publish_stream,manage_pages,publish_actions
3. next, I've created a script to post content, basically this is it:

   ```
   $appId='12822*****98');
   $secret='17c*****************320f');

   // on récupére l'instance de classe Facebook
   $facebook=new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $appId,
      'secret' => $secret
   ));

   // acquisition du token
   $url='https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?'.
       'client_id='.$appId.
       '&client_secret='.$secret.
       '&grant_type=client_credentials'.           '&scope=read_stream,publish_stream,publish_actions,manage_pages,offline_access'.
     '&state=dfgdfgdtgdgfdfg';
   $reponse = file_get_contents($url); 
   $tabReponse=explode('=',$reponse);
   $accessToken=$tabReponse[1];
   $facebook->setAccessToken($accessToken);

   $params = array(
       'message' => 'the message',
       'link' => 'http://www.myAppUrl.com'),
       'name'    => 'the name',
       'description' => 'some description',
   );

   try {                           
   // la cible
   $targetID='1471*********81';

   // publication
   $publishStream = $facebook->api("/$targetID/feed/", 'POST',     $params);           

   } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
       $result = $e->getResult();
       print("Attention, la publication FB a échoué, veuillez vérifier les paramètres!");
   }
   ```

If I print the access token delivered on the first step, I get something like `{appId}|***************************` (27 caracters), which I've read on [this old post](http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/facebook-graph-api-getting-access-tokens/) is a valid token for some operations but not all.
With this, I can publish on my personal wall, but not on a page I admin, in this last case, I get a `#200 error` (about user that has not authorized the app to do this action).

If I use the Graph API Explorer to generate an access token for my app, I get a long string representing the access token, and if I use it in the `setAccessToken` invoke, the I can quite publish on the page. Since I get a `#100 error` (about links that must refer to Canvas URL, even if "Stream post URL security:" is set Off on the app settings)

**Does someone know how to achieve what I want?**

I don't want any USER connection, it is the server who must request credentials to post through the app, not a user.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems getting app to post to a page](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9066941/problems-getting-app-to-post-to-a-page). It's important to not that you will not be able to post to page without identity of user. (and if you want it be posted as page you need identity of user who is admin of the page)

Comment: Indeed. But I can't see any answer there. Since I've put the code I've used here, can you explain where I've missed something?
Thanks in advance!